# How to navigate to different bottom tab navigation in specific screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have bottom tab navigation, as example I have attached screen with navigation.
[image]

Framework: React Native, react native navigation v6.
Question: I need to navigate from Home tab to the second screen in Settings tab and I need to have possibility to go back to the first screen in Settings Tab.

```
    navigation.navigate("SettingsTab", {
         screen: "EmailEditScreen",
       });
```

I've made quite easy but when i navigate as above, I can't go back to the first screen of Settings Tab. When i switch tabs between Home and Settings always display the second screen of Settings Tab and I cant go back to the first Screen Profile in Settings. Im stuck on EmailEditScreen forever. So the question is: how to change tab to the specific screen correctly?

I want to change bottom tab and go to the specific screen but also I need to have back history of navigation to go back to previous screen in that bottom tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add "initial" params in target screen:

```
navigation.navigate("SettingsTab", {
    screen: "EmailEditScreen",
    initial: true
});
```

See: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#rendering-initial-route-defined-in-the-navigator

But back behavior is still buggy (if you navigate from a subscreen of Home stack to subscreen of Settings Stack for example) & target screen tab stay on initial subscreen too if you press on bottom bar :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it in a two step process

```
navigation.navigate("SettingsTab")
navigation.navigate("EmailEditScreen")
```

In the approach you are adopting, you only push one element to the stack. This way, you'd be pushing two elements to the stack navigator and navigating to the `SettingsTab` should be possible.